# How to change font color of a string that im using in an outlook message?

Tags: vba, string, fonts, colors, outlook

I have a string object :

```
Dim text As String

text="HOLA"
```

and then im using it in a mail body like this:

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = correo
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "greetings" 
        .HTMLBody = Msg & text & "<br><br><br>" & text2 
        .Send
    End With
```

I want to change the font color, style and size of the "text" variable.

Thanks a lot, I hope you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using HTML, you can put the text into eg `<span>` node, add [`style` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp), and set [`color`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp) and [`font`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp) properties:

```
text = cell.Value
htmlcontent = "<span style='color: red; font: 15px arial, sans-serif;'>" & text & "</span>"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! and what about if text is not equal to HOLA but a value taken from excel: {text=cell.Value}

Comment: @FedericoSalinas you can concatenate HTML parts and the variable value, I added to the answer.